# How is this algorithm working?! Can someone explain it to me please..have an interview tomorrow

Tags: python

```
def sum_in(numbers, sum_):
    """whether any two numbers from `numbers` form `sum_`."""
    return any((sum_-n) in numbers for n in numbers)
```

It basically takes a list, and checks if any two numbers from it form a sum equalling sum_. I can't seem to get how that sum_-n verifies that TWO numbers equal the sum. Wouldn't it just be checking with one n each loop?!

Answer (score 3):

It's checking `sum_-n` is in numbers.  If it is, then that `number + n = sum_`.

Answer (score 1):

For each iteration, a `bool` is generated whether (`sum_` -  `n`) is in the set of `numbers`. If one of these `bool`s is `True`, the function returns `True`. It returns `False` otherwise, clearly.

This is not a great algorithm, to put it mildly.

Consider:

```
sum_in((3,), 6)
```

This will return `True`. Why? Because `6 - 3` is in `numbers`.

So yes, it is only checking **one value** in each iteration.

Good luck with the interview!